# Internal Server Error connecting to Django database

Tags: python, django, backend

I have a connection function built to write data to my database.
Here's the connect function from views.py

```
def _parse_body(body):
    body_unicode = body.decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(body_unicode)

@csrf_exempt
def connect(request):
    body = _parse_body(request.body)
    connection_id = body['connectionId']
    connect = Connection(connection_id=connection_id)
    connect.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message":"connect successfully"}, status=200)
```

And the models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Connection(models.Model):
    connection_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Testing the connect api on postman and with curl returns a 500 internal server error like this:
[connect testing on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCjmh.png)

Here's also the stacktrace:
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxEX0.png)

Comment: The JSON you are sending is no proper, can you please post the JSON that is sent with this request?

Comment: curl -d "{\"key\":\"value\"}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/websocket/connect/

Comment: curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/websocket/connect It should be like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably sending a message like:

```
{connectionId: "something"}
```

When you should instead enclose the property name `connectionId` in double quotes to be a valid JSON message:

```
{"connectionId": "something"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the JSON you are sending to the server is not properly formatted. And because it is an invalid JSON you are getting an error at line `body = _parse_body(request.body)`

Your curl should look like this

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8000/websocket/connect
```